# Python calling PyFIles

Tags: python, call

How Can I call a Python Script From anonther Python Script

I tried using os system and tried using this

```
def run(runfile):
  with open(runfile,"r") as rnf:
    exec(rnf.read())

print ("Welcome")

print ("Programs.")
print ("1. Vowel Counter")
print ("2. Basic Calculator")
print ("3. Odd Even")

program = int(input("Select a Program by Choosing its number: "))
programs = ["1", "2", "3"]


if program == "1" :
    execfile('VowelCounter.py')
```

There's no Error but it wont run the other py file

Comment: why is `VowelCounter.py` not a module that you `import` (and call function from)? that would be the pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Even though python has the capabilities to run external script using **exec** and **execfile**, the more pythonic way of doing is by importing packages.

But I understand that you target can only be known at run time, you could use **importlib**, to import a package dynamically.

A sample is given below

```
# Order should be re arranged as per your need
programs = {
    "1": {'package': "VowelCounter", "desc": "1. Vowel Counter"},
    "2": {'package': "BasicCalculator", "desc": "2. Basic Calculator"}
}

for item in programs.values():
    print(item['desc'])

program_idx = input("Select a Program by Choosing its number: ")

imp_module = importlib.import_module(programs[program_idx]['package'])
main_method = getattr(imp_module, "main")

main_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the program variable as `int` here

```
program = int(input("Select a Program by Choosing its number: "))
```

Then you are checking the value as string

```
if program == "1" :
```

It must be

```
if program == 1 :
```

I think that should be the problem. If not you will get the real problem after this!

Comment: I think execfile has some issues in python3 . try this 
 exec(open("VowelCounter.py").read())

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

print("Welcome")

print("Programs.")
print("1. Vowel Counter")
print("2. Basic Calculator")
print("3. Odd Even")

program = input("Select a Program by Choosing its number: ")
programs = ["1", "2", "3"]

program_files = {'1': 'VowelCounter', '2': 'BasicCalculator', '3': 'OddEven'}
if program in "123" :
    cmd = f'python {program_files[program]}.py'
    print('Running -->', cmd)
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: it shows  'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.